# Transition rate of two level system subjected to noise

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, noise, open-quantum-systems, stochastic-processes

(this question is simpler than its length implies.
I did this on purpose to provide a nice complete development for future readers)

## The setup

Suppose we have a two-level quantum system with Hamiltonian

$$H/\hbar = -\frac{\Omega}{2} \left[ I(t)\sigma_x + Q(t) \sigma_y \right] \, .$$

Now suppose that both $I(t)$ and $Q(t)$ are noisy with constant power spectral densities and have zero mean.
What is the probability that the system, when prepared in $|0\rangle$, is found in $|1\rangle$ at a later time?

## My calculation

For an arbitrary signal $I(t)$, and taking $Q(t)=0$, we can write the propagator easily:

$$U(t) =
\cos (\theta/2)\mathbf{1}
-i\sin ( \theta / 2 )\sigma_x$$

where

$$\theta = \left[\Omega \int_0^t I(t')\,\mathrm dt' \right] \, .$$

Denoting the (single sided) spectral density of $I(t)$ as $S_I(\omega$), we can then compute the mean square angle using the [Wiener-Khinchin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem) theorem:

\begin{align}
\langle \theta^2 \rangle
&= \Omega^2 \int_0^t \int_0^t \mathrm dt' \, \mathrm dt'' \, \langle I(t')I(t'')\rangle \\
&= \Omega^2 \int_0^t \int_0^t \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm dt'\,\mathrm dt''\,\frac{\mathrm d\omega}{2\pi} S_I(\omega)\cos(\omega (t'-t'')) \\
&= \Omega^2 t^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{2\pi} S_I(\omega) \frac{\sin(\omega t / 2)^2}{(\omega t / 2)^2} \\
(\text{Assume }S_I(\omega)=S_I)\quad &= \frac{1}{2} \Omega^2 t S_I \, .
\end{align}

Note that $\theta$ is probably Gaussian distributed because it arises from the accumulation of many little inputs of $I(t)$.
Now, the probability $P_0$ to find the system still in $|0\rangle$ after being kicked around by $I(t)$ is the average of $\cos(\theta / 2)^2$:

\begin{align}
P_0 &= \langle \cos(\theta / 2)^2 \rangle \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \langle \cos \theta \rangle \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \langle e^{i \theta} \rangle \right)
\quad \text{(because $\theta$ is symmetrically distributed)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \exp \left[- \frac{1}{2} \langle \theta^2 \rangle \right] \right)
\quad \text{(special property of Gaussian distributions)} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \exp \left[ -\frac{1}{4} \Omega^2 S_I t \right] \right) \, .
\end{align}

This is easily interpreted as a transition *rate* of

$$\Gamma = \frac{1}{4} \Omega^2 S_I \, .$$

## The tricky bit

The problem comes in when $Q(t) \neq 0$.
For small angles we can approximate the total rotational angle as

$$\theta^2 = \theta_I^2 + \theta_Q^2$$

where $\theta_I$ is the rotation angle which we would have if $Q(t)$ were zero, and $\theta_Q$ is the rotation angle we would have if $I(t)$ were zero.
This is just the pythagorean theorem applied to a linearized patch of the sphere near $|0\rangle$.
In this case we get

$$\Gamma = \frac{1}{2} \Omega^2 S_{I,Q}$$

which is just twice the rate we found in the case $Q(t)=0$.

In the full problem where we do not assume small angles, what can we still say?
Is the system still described by a transition rate or is the dynamics more complex?
If we can use a rate how do we calculate it?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I don't really have time to think about the question properly at the moment, but here are some thoughts. The model with $Q(t) = 0$ is rather special because the noise term commutes with itself at different times. Such a model can be termed a *pure dephasing* model (although this term has other uses), and is known to be exactly solvable. When $Q(t)\neq 0$ the noise term does not commute with itself at different times and I very much doubt an exact solution is possible. If you use perturbation theory you can probably derive a Markovian master equation that contains transition rates.

Comment: [contd.] The Markovian approximation should work fairly well here since you are assuming perfect white noise. I am afraid I don't have much experience with random Hamiltonians, so your methods here are rather obscure to me. My guess is that you should employ a cumulant expansion of the propagator and truncate at second order. If you rewrite this as a dynamical equation you will get a master equation out with the desired transition rates. I believe that this type of procedure is explained in van Kampen's book on Stochastic Methods. I hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: Thank you for the information. As you say, the difficulty comes fundamentally from the fact that rotations around the $x$ and $y$ axes are non-commuting. The book reference may help. Thanks again.